# Where init a module passing API key in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Hey guys I need to init a module in expressjs passing the API key and starting to make in that way requests. Where is the right way and to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use environment variables.

Run your app:

```
KEY=secretkey node server.js
```

Inside your app:

```
var key = process.env.KEY;
// ... use the key
```